# Use a string in PHP "as is"

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a string in PHP with special characters, like: "��J�v��LX�R�8�)�
/외�Qհ<�*����d�". Sometimes, in the middle of this string, could appear simbol like /n or /r and when I save this string into a session variable, those characters are removed. iHow i can save and use this special string "as is" witout any kind of transformation from PHP?

Steps: Before create a string to encypt and after encrypt it.

```
$encryptedString = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $secretKey, $valueToEncrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

After I save this encrypted data (as "��J�v��LX�R�8�)�\r/외�Qհ<�*����d�") to session variable.

```
$_SESSION['hashPass'] = (string)$encryptedString;
```

When I compare the 2 strings (with == and === operators both), result is false cause the session variable appear like: "��J�v��LX�R�8�)�/외�Qհ<�*����d�"... \r is missing...

Comment: Have you tried using simple `'` instead of double quote `"` ?

Comment: Did you try to replace \ with \\ ?

Comment: `/n`? That has no special meaning in PHP whatsoever. `\n` in a double-quoted string would be a newline char... But even that will go into/out of a session var without change. `\n` viewed in a browser would be treated like a regular space char, however.

Comment: I have try a cast (string) but nothing happen.

Comment: marc B, yes I mean \n I've wrong slash... But when I save this string into a session and take it again, \n is replaced with a space... I'm in debug with NetBeans, then no browser are used...

Comment: What does this have to do with session variables? Show your code.

Comment: "��J�v��LX�R�8�)�\r/외�Qհ<�*����d�" this is another sample... \r this time, is replaced with a space. But entire string is a password cryped, I cannot change nothing...

Comment: FRED: $hashedLogin= mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $secretKey, $uncruptedValue, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB); $_SESSION['hashLogin'] = (string)$hashedLogin; - This is the code. It's simple but when I get data from $_SESSION['hashLogin'] some characters are missing... in some sample I see /r an /n

Comment: Please post your code in your question, instead of inside comments.

Comment: OK, sorry... The code is now in the questions.

Comment: If you say you have characters like `��J�v��LX�R�8�)� /외`, then those `�` shouldn't be there in the first place. You have an encoding issue.

Comment: What king of encoding I can use to store and use myrypt_encrypt output?

Comment: The file's encoding. Is it UTF-8?

Comment: i've try to use utf8_encode. From "áÉJÎv½ûLXðRû8ó)×\r/ì¸QÕ°<*ÿòd®" become "áÉJÎv½ûLXðRû8ó)×/ì¸QÕ°<*ÿòd®" after saving data into session... Nothing has changed :(